# Confusion Matrix changing with every interation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, confusion-matrix

I am constructing a Confusion Matrix for six classes and I am using [scikit_learn confusion matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#example-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py) as the base code for plotting the matrix. 
I am facing the problem that whenever I re-train the Linear SVM Classifier the Confusion Matrix is changed with every training session. No. of predicted labels remains the same and no. of true labels also remains the same for every interation. I am unable to understand why Confusion Matrix is changing this way. The diagonal elements are also not making any sense.

Please guide me what should I do.

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, title='Confusion matrix', cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(6)
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, names, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, names)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label') 
    # this is the main function i am using
    # here names is a list of six titles e.g. names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']


#Following is the code that I am using to call the function
cm = confusion_matrix(labels_test, predicted)
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')
print(cm)
plt.figure()
plot_confusion_matrix(cm)
cm_normalized = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
print('Normalized confusion matrix')
print(cm_normalized)
plt.figure()
plot_confusion_matrix(cm_normalized, title='Normalized confusion matrix')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

A confusion matrix allows you to understand where does your classifier do well (true positives) and where it doesn't (false positives).

The diagonals of a confusion matrix tells you how many times a particular class was correctly classified (True positives).

Seems like your classifier changes from iteration when you retrain your dataset. Therefore the number of true positives/false positives/true negatives/false negatives may be different.

Comment: I was of the notion that if all the feature vector set and the SVM parameters remains constant, the classifier itself will remain the same. The classification report turns out to be the same every time but conf. matrix is varying.

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends on alot of things. You'll need to provide more details. Looking at the documentation online: "Note that the LinearSVC also implements an alternative multi-class strategy, the so-called multi-class SVM formulated by Crammer and Singer, by using the option multi_class='crammer_singer'. This method is consistent, which is not true for one-vs-rest classification. In practice, one-vs-rest classification is usually preferred, since the results are mostly similar, but the runtime is significantly less."

Comment: I have tried training the SVM with "multi_class=crammer_singer" option. It took a while against the time that Linear SVC took during the training phase. But at the end the confusion matrix is still varying when I plot it. Can you give me some contact info so that I can relay you more info regarding my specific problem?

Comment: You can edit your question and add more information there.